# how to select loose geometry part in one object

Tags: objects, edit-mode, selection-tools, select

[image]

The full sphere is one object, which exists of loose geometry parts (planks). How can I select a single part without separating the complete object?

Comment: To select a single plank : Edit mode > Face select mode > hover mouse over one of the faces of a plank and hit the L key.

Comment: That worked, thanks!